# Why does EF 4.1 code first returns a HashSet instead of a Collection

Tags: ef-code-first, devexpress, entity-framework-4.1, hashset

Getting this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Counter]
```

Expecting this:

```
ICollection<Counter>
```

//underlying Object:

```
public virtual ICollection<Counter> Counters { get; private set; }
```

I'm using DevExpress PropertyGridControl:

```
dxprg:CollectionDefinition Path="Counters" Type="{x:Type efo:Counter}"
```

I take it this normal behavior for EF considering I'm not calling any function on the Collection of counters like, for example, ToList()  but because of the Path property on the CollectionDefenition it's not clear how to do so.
I could create a real-time object, populate it with equal values, init the Collection and then Bind to it but that seems really dirty.

Any wisdom on what is happening here with regard to EF is welcome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework needs *something* to implement the `ICollection` It uses [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because that is a rather efficient `ICollection<T>` implementation. In the end, every object implementing an interface is always some concrete class.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So, I'm going to have to create the object at the UI level with a typeof Collection as the "concrete class". 
Is this right?

Comment: If you initialize the collection yourself, yes, it should be an `ICollection<T>` implementation. HashSet also serves well because it has unique elements, so they map well to database records.

Comment: `[NotMapped] public IList<Counter> CountersList {
   get { return this.Counters.ToList( ); }
 }` Placed in the Entity Counter Object Solves the problem in a reasonably tidy way. Thanks Gert.